# Customize Path to REST params in Pageable

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I am using spring to build a REST api with PageAble, to get numberofPages,itens...

first, i did a mapping like this

```
  public ResponseEntity<Data> findByName(@PathVariable(value="name",required=true) String name, @RequestParam(value="page", defaultValue="0") Integer page, @RequestParam(value="qtd", defaultValue="10") Integer linesPerPage, @RequestParam(value="sort", defaultValue="nome") String sort, @RequestParam(value="direction", defaultValue="ASC") String direction)
```

So in my url i get for example "url?name=erick&direction=asc" but i need to change to "url?name=erick!asc"

How can i change it?

Comment: Why you need to change a standard convention to a weird one? Otherwise you can parse name variable to controller and then pass as is.

Comment: i thought weird, but it was the company .. so ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Look at page 3 of https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Answer (score 0):

In you case,you should use @RequestParam("name") instead of @PathVariable.Then the request url will be like "url?name=erick&direction=asc"

Spring has three kinds of Annotation.

- @PathVariable

This annotation means the variable is on the url.For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public void pathVariable(@PathVariable("id") Long id){}
```

The variable was put between the brace at the url.

- @RequestParam

This annotation means the variable is part of the quest param,the request url looks like

> stackoverflow.com?name=hhhh

For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public void requestParam(@RequestParam("id")Long id){}
```

- @RequestBody

This annotation means you will receive some data from request body.And some kind of converter,like jackson,will convert it into a properly object.For example:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public void requestBody(@RequestBody Example example){}
```